# Android: Not getting how popBackStackImmediate () behaves

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I have 3 Fragments and the flow is like

> Fragment 1 --> Fragment 2 (adding it to back stack)--> Fragment 3 --> Fragment 1

As I want to go to Fragment 1 from Fragment 3 again, I want the back stack to be clean so that when user press back nothing happens.

Intially I have cleared popback stack at Fragment 3

```
Boolean isPoped = fManager.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

And then created a new Instance of my fragment 1

```
HomeFragment homeFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance(mobileNumber, "");
FragmentTransaction transaction =fManager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, homeFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

which caused 
[android: ViewPager throwing null pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827391/android-viewpaager-throwing-null-pointer)

then I commented the above code and only used

```
Boolean isPoped = fManager.popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

which works fine as it removed the transactions(that I belive) and took me to homeFragment but that caused [View pager not instantiating post fragment popBackStackImmediate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911593/view-pager-not-instantiating-post-fragment-popbackstackimmediate)

Here I am not getting how popBackStack works? All I want is to take user from Fragment 3 to Fragment 1 and clear the backstack.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at your code in the other question and I think I understand what the problem is.

So your first action is that you create Fragment 1 and put it in a container.  I don't see code for that but no matter; if the container is empty then `add` and `replace` act the same way.  So now your Fragment 1 is in the container.

You haven't called `addToBackStack` here so the `FragmentManager` doesn't know how to undo this operation.  That's fine, it's the first operation and doesn't need to be undone.

Next you create Fragment 2 and do a `replace` transaction. Fragment 1 is replaced with Fragment 2.  This is pushed to the back stack so the `FragmentManager` *does* know how to undo this transaction.

Next you create Fragment 3 and do a `replace` transaction. Fragment 2 is replaced with Fragment 3.  You don't push this operation to the back stack. Uh oh.

Now when you say `popBackStack` (deferred or immediate) the `FragmentManager` goes to undo the operation to replace Fragment 2 with Fragment 1 *but Fragment 2 isn't in the container anymore*.  So (from what I understand) the `FragmentManager` will put Fragment 1 back in the container but leave Fragment 3 there.  It doesn't know what to do with Fragment 3.

---

Here is how I handle those kinds of scenarios:  Say I have Fragment 1, then navigate to Fragment 2.  To navigate to Fragment 3 when I intend the back button to go to Fragment 1, I do this:

1. Pop the back stack (immediate, now Fragment 1 is back in the container) then
2. Replace Fragment 1 with Fragment 3 and push that operation to the back stack.

Now when I press the back button, the `FragmentManager` knows how to undo my operation and puts Fragment 1 back where Fragment 3 was.  This means that I don't have to perform any fragment transactions to handle this back navigation, the `FragmentManager` handles it all for me.

Comment: Your `ViewPager` issue is another matter.  I'm going to add an answer there specific to that question.